# How to use variables in debhelper dh_gencontrol?

Tags: debhelper, debian-packaging

I'm trying to append data to a Debian package's description during the build process.
The required data is stored in constants declared within `debian/rules` file.

I've override `dh_gencontrol` and added `@printf` calls which formats the data.

The issues I'm encountering are related to whitespace-containing-strings:

1. `printf` splits the given string, matching each word to an `%s` instance. I'd like it to use the whole string instead.
2. How can I manipulate said string, replacing spaces with `_` and add it to the same line?

Relevant sections from `debian/rules`:

```
TEXT_STRING = "string with data"
VERSION_NUM = "v11.4"
...
...
override_dh_gencontrol:
    dh_gencontrol
    @echo "Adding versions to debian/control file"   # This one writes to console
    @printf " %-30s %-20s %s\n" "${TEXT_STRING// /_}" "${VERSION_NUM}" "${TEXT_STRING}" >> "$(CURDIR)/debian/my-package/DEBIAN/control"
```

Expected output:

```
<Package description generated by dh_gencontrol>
 string_with_data            v11.4               string with data
```

Actual output:

```
                             v11.4               string
 with                        data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 main issues here:

1. Bash substitution (i.e. `"${TEXT_STRING// /_}"`) does not work inside the make file.

   Solution is to perform string manipulation within a (on-the-fly) shell session, like so:
   `$(shell echo ${TEXT_STRING} | sed 's/ /_/g')`
2. String with spaces breaks up into list of words. `printf` sees them as multiple variables, were each one "consumes" a single `%s`

   This results in `printf` adding additional lines until printing all variables.

   This is solved by removing the quote marks wrapping the string, turning this `"${TEXT_STRING}"` to that `${TEXT_STRING}`.

The final solution would be:

```
@printf " %-30s %-20s %s\n" $(shell echo ${TEXT_STRING} | sed 's/ /_/g') ${VERSION_NUM} ${TEXT_STRING} >> "$(CURDIR)/debian/my-package/DEBIAN/control"
```